# Value returned after numericUpDown1 value exceeds the maximum range (C# Windows Form)

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, runtime-error, numericupdown

I set a minimum value of 1 and maximum of 10 for my "numericUpDown1". (C# Windows Form)

When I enter the value 0 manually from the keyboard, "numericUpDown1" automatically increases to 1, and when I enter a value greater than 10 manually from the keyboard, "numericUpDown1" automatically decreases to 10.

Is it possible for me to change these automatic returns? Ex: If I type 25, it will return 3 instead of 10.

Is there any option/property to change this?

I tried some options like "Validated", "Validating", "Leave" and "ValueChanged". But that didn't work.

When it is <=0 or >10, I wanted to return an error (messagebox) and automatically return the value of "numericUpDown1" to 1.

Comment: Not sure how to answer this. But if you want to validate yourself the number then do not specify the min/max value!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to handle the `KeyDown` event. The approach I would personally use is to inherit `NumericUpDown` and replace instances of it in the MainForm.Designer.cs file with my custom class. Now, if you set the value of `Maximum` to 10 in the designer it will behave the way you describe.

[image: screenshot]

---

```
class NumericUpDownEx : NumericUpDown
{
    // Disable range checking in the base class.
    public NumericUpDownEx()
    {
        base.Maximum = decimal.MaxValue;
        base.Minimum = decimal.MinValue;
    }
    public new decimal Maximum { get; set; } = 100; // Keep default value the same
    public new decimal Minimum { get; set; } = 0;   // Keep default value the same

    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnKeyDown(e);
        switch (e.KeyData)
        {
            case Keys.Enter:
                e.Handled = e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
                BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {
                    // In this case, Designer has set Min = 1, Max = 10
                    if (Value < Minimum || Value > Maximum)
                    {
                        var message = $"Error: '{Value}' is not legal.";
                        Value = 1;
                        MessageBox.Show(message);
                        Focus();
                    }
                    var length = Value.ToString().Length;
                    if (length > 0)
                    {
                        Select(0, length);
                    }
                });
                break;
        }
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

You'll also want to do the same kind of action when the control loses focus.

```
    .
    .
    .
    /// <summary>
    ///  The Validating event doesn't always fire when we want it to,
    ///  especially if this is the only control. Do this instead;
    /// </summary>
    protected override void OnLostFocus(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLostFocus(e); 
        OnKeyDown(new KeyEventArgs(Keys.Enter));
    }
```

Comment: It worked very well, Thank you very much!

 It was a very useful base for me study and learn about how some default settings work and can be modify, like Keyboard press key, Mouse scroll, Mouse click held down...